Issue with connecting Keycloak with Spring boot
I am trying to connect my keycloak to spring boot app in my application.yml always I get problem with this property keycloak.auth-server-url
keycloak:
  realm: test
  resource: test
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  credentials:
    secret:
  ssl-required: external
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  bearer-only: true
  public-client: true
  cors: true
  principal-attribute: admin 

The version of keycloak that I am using is 25.0.4 (the latest one).
I expect the connection to pass successfully between keycloak and spring boot.

I see the question is tagged with realm which is part of MongoDB Realm the database. Can you clarify how the question relates?
